# Is there a Fisher Information equivalent in MAP Empirical Bayes estimation?

Tags: linear, fisher-information, optimal

**Background**

The Fisher information for a linear Gaussian model is
$\mathcal{I}_{\theta} = \frac{X X^T}{\sigma^2} $. This is used in optimal experiment design techniques, for example, maximisation of $| \mathcal{I}_{\theta} |$ is called D-optimal design, which maximises the confidence in our estimation.

Even for non-uniform priors, I assume that this would be still a target for optimisation in experiment design because the prior is not influenced by the data.

However in Empirical Bayes techniques (type II MAP), the priors are influenced by the data. I assume then it would make sense to use another metric which takes into account what excitations of the model would bring about more posterior evidence.

**Question**

For a linear Gaussian model with $ y = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\theta} \mathbf{X} ,\mathbf{\Sigma}^2) $, and $ \theta = ~ \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{\Gamma}) $ so that the prior distribution is assumed to be normal, how would one derive a formula for an alternative Fisher information $| \mathcal{I}_{\theta,II} |$  which could be maximised to find the most informative excitations of a Bayesian probability model?

Comment: Are you looking for a similar criterion to find create an optimal design? In maximum likelihood estimation, the information matrix is the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix; so the D-optimal design is one that either maximizes the determinant of the information matrix or minimizes the determinant of the variance-covariance matrix. In the Bayesian setting, a D-optimal design is one that minimizes the posterior variance-covariance matrix of the design. There are "pseudo"-Bayesian methods that average the determinant using the prior distribution. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I was looking for this two years ago, yes. Could you give some reference to these methods or explain briefly in an answer how do fhey work? I think OED questions are relevant for Bayesian models, but I didn’t find a good one for Sparse Bayesian Learning / ARD based regression, back then.

Comment: ARD? Automatic Relevance Determination? I don't know much about Sparse Bayesian Learning for OED, or anything really. I only know about Bayesian methods in general. I could maybe answer something.

Have you looked at "Bayesian Experimental Design: A Review"  by Kathryn Chaloner and Isabella Verdinelli or "A Review of Modern Computational Algorithms for Bayesian Optimal Design" by E.G. Ryan, C.C. Drovandi, J.M. McGree, and A.N. Pettitt??

Answer (score 1):

The Fisher Information matrix has nothing to do with the MAP. The posterior is calculated by the product of the likelihood and the prior. The Fisher Information is the double-derivative of the likelihood function and gives the asymptotic variance of the maximum likelihood estimate. It just so happens that when parametric modeling assumptions are met, it is the *exact* variance of the MLE.

The posterior mode is a different quantity in finite samples. People aren't quite sure how to find the variance of a mode. The Fisher Information would be a biased estimate of its variance because it does not incorporate the prior (it may be reasonable in large sample sizes or when the prior is very noninformative, in which case you're just using Bayes to approximate frequentist estimates).

Comment: I understand that the metric that I'm seeking is not the Fisher Information, I'm looking for an alternative. I'm not sure I understand your point about the posterior mode, apart from the fact that the mode and the mean indeed does not coincide when the distribution is asymmetric. In the example of Gaussian prior and likelihood I mentioned above, this is not the case as I know. In this case also the variance of the posterior is a tractable quantity. Is your point then that the minimisation of the determinant of this variance could then be a target for D-optimality?